# Query refresh rows in dashboard CloudBoost

Tags: android, cloudboost

After using query insert, update, delete row . What query can help me to refresh database ? 
Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0):

The database does not need to be "refreshed". You can however, refresh your interface/dataset with a CloudQuery (https://tutorials.cloudboost.io/en/query/basicqueries) or you can listen realtime events on queries and have a notification triggered automatically on your client which will be responsible for refreshing the UI. You can check Realtime Queries here (https://tutorials.cloudboost.io/en/realtime/cloudobjectnotifications)